# start-Transcript not capturing all output to log file..?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the below code that goes through and gets scheduled tasks info and puts the output that occurs on the screen to a log file.

However, what I have noticed is that all errors are logged EXCEPT for servers that have "Access is denied" - how can I log those errors in the log file as well.

Below is the code:

```
Start-Transcript -path $scheduledpath\logging.txt -append

foreach ($name in $names) 
{
    Write-Host "Running Against Server $name" -ForegroundColor Magenta
    if ( Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ) 
        {
            #$Command = "schtasks.exe /query /S $name /fo CSV /v >c:\tools\Scheduled\$name.csv"
            $Command = "schtasks.exe /query /S $name /fo CSV /v >$scheduledpath\$name.csv"
            Invoke-Expression $Command
            Clear-Variable Command -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }

    else{
            Write-Host "$name is Down" -ForegroundColor Red
        }

}

Stop-Transcript
```

Here is the output on the screen:

```
> Running Against Server SV064909 
> SV064909 is Down 
> Running Against Server SV081372 
> SV081372 is Down 
> Running Against Server YBEF008690_vorher_SV064930 
> YBEF008690_vorher_SV064930 is Down 
> Running Against Server Alt_SV064921 
> Alt_SV064921 is Down 
> Running Against Server SV073632 
> ERROR: Access is denied. 
> Running Against Server SV073633 
> ERROR: Access is denied.
```

Here is the output in the LOG file....no ACCESS IS DENIED Shown...?

```
> Running Against Server SV064909 
> SV064909 is Down 
> Running Against Server SV081372 
> SV081372 is Down 
> Running Against Server YBEF008690_vorher_SV064930 
> YBEF008690_vorher_SV064930 is Down 
> Running Against Server Alt_SV064921 
> Alt_SV064921 is Down 
> Running Against Server SV073632 
> Running Against Server SV073633
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This behavior with native command output not being recorded in Start-Transcript output but being output to the console is reported in connect bug [315857](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/315875/unable-to-capture-all-session-output-into-a-transcript). See workarounds for possible solutions.

Comment: And now the link is broken and with it all the workarounds :-(

Comment: [Resurrected link](http://web.archive.org/web/20130608164153/http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/315875/unable-to-capture-all-session-output-into-a-transcript)

Comment: GitHub issue [10994](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10994)

Answer (score 12):

The simplest workaround is to pipe the results of the native command to `Out-Host`

```
schtasks.exe /query /S $name /fo CSV /v >$scheduledpath\$name.csv | Out-Host
```

Comment: And now, the pipeline is burst, and you can't pipe your output to anything else. That's the most obvious drawback of this workaround.

Comment: I suspect that
(schtasks.exe /query /S $name /fo CSV /v >$scheduledpath\$name.csv | Out-Host)
will unburst the pipeline, although not handle errors now.

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked for me.
I found [a link from 2009](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2009/03/06/effective-powershell-item-14-capturing-all-output-from-a-script/) with discussions of the issue. But a microsoft [blog from 2010](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2010/01/04/workaround-for-start-transcript-on-native-processes/) solved the issue for me.

In short, pipe the native command output to Out-Default.

```
  schtasks.exe /query /S $name /fo CSV /v | Out-Default
```

{I didn't really try that line myself, but you get the idea.}

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, the correct answer should be:

```
$Command = "schtasks.exe /query /S $name /fo CSV /v 2>&1 >$scheduledpath\$name.csv"
```

I.e. pipe stderror (pipe 2) to stdout (pipe 1), so that both shows in the stdout.

Answer (score 0):

## Get service tag

```
    $servicetag = Get-WmiObject win32_bios | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SerialNumber 
    Write-output $servicetag
```

I used Write-output in one line at the top of my script,
after that one they were all Write-Host. But every "Write" output is now showing up in my script.