# Powershell Tracing and Control-M

Tags: windows, powershell, control-m

I seem to have run into a problem/bug when trying to capture tracing output when running a Powershell script from Control-M.

The output file shows the headers and footers of the start-trace and stop-trace commands, but it does not show anything else I try to capture.  Specifically, if my script issues a write-host command somewhere, then that information is not captured in the output (trace) file.

Here is a super simple script that illustraes my problem:

```
start-transcript -path "C:\Powershell\transcript.log"
write-host "test message"
#do stuff...
stop-transcript
```

Here is an example of my current output when running the script through Control-M:

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell Transcript Start
Start time: 20140212002005
Username  : mydomain\SYSTEM 
Machine   : myserver (Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1) 
**********************
**********************
Windows PowerShell Transcript End
End time: 20140212002008
**********************
```

Note that my test message does not show up!  This only happens when I run the script via Control-M.  When I run my script manually, my "test message" does show up in the transcript output.

My first suspicion was file permissions, but those look good to me.  The Control-M agent uses system level access, so it should have all the permissions it needs anyway.  If it were a file permission issue, I don't believe i would even get the header/footer messages.

I'm on PS v2.0.  My server is running 2008r2.

Any thoughts appreciated...

Comment: possible duplicate of [start-Transcript not capturing all output to log file..?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160759/start-transcript-not-capturing-all-output-to-log-file)

Answer (score 1):

`Write-Host` writes to to the console window, which is not what's being "watched" by Control-M. Try `Write-Output` instead. `Write-Host` is usually *not* what you want for producing output.

See http://windowsitpro.com/blog/what-do-not-do-powershell-part-1 and http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/donjones/archive/2012/04/06/2012-scripting-games-commentary-stop-using-write-host.aspx

Comment: write-output doesn't allow me to write to the same transcript file.  I thought one of the big advantages of transcript is that it captures all the output for you, as evidenced when I run my script outside of Control-M.  I'm not using write-host to create programmatic usable output; it is simply information for anyone who needs to monitor the script (debugging, whatever).

Comment: Thanks alroc... in reference to your links above, I tried the write-verbose technique.  But unfortunately im having the same problem.  Control-M seems to have some kind of effect on Powershell in that logging and tracing is essentially non-functional.

Comment: Start-Transcript doesn't work well outside of the interactive mode and I don't think it's meant to. From the cmdlet's own description: " The transcript includes all command **that the user types and all output that appears on the console**." If a full log is critical for this process, write your own logging instead of relying upon something that wasn't meant for the task.