# Start-Transcript and Logging Batch File Output

Tags: powershell, batch-file, logging, module, transcription

I have a function in a PowerShell module which creates a log file and starts a transcript using that file (see below). When running a PowerShell script, this works great and captures all output.

When running a PowerShell script which calls a batch file (which we do quite often while migrating from CMD > PowerShell), the batch file output shows on the console in the same window as the PowerShell script, but the transcript log file shows only 1 blank line where the call to the batch file is.

```
09:53:25 AM [Success] Zip file already up to date, no need to download!
09:53:25 AM [Note   ] Calling 1.bat

10:07:55 AM [Note   ] Calling 2.bat
```

I'm calling the batch files from .ps1 scripts with only the ampersand '&'.

What's strange is that sometimes the batch file output *is* captured in the log (usually the first batch file called). However I can't find anything special about these files.

What's also strange is that sometimes we call external programs (WinSCP) and the output from those commands only *sometimes* show in the transcript. Possibly relevant.

For reference, here is the function I use to create a transcript of our processes.

```
Function Log_Begin()
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Starts the process for logging a PowerShell script.
    .DESCRIPTION
    Starts the process for logging a PowerShell script. This means that whenever
    this function is called from a PowerShell script, a folder called 'Logs' will
    be created in the same folder, containing a full transcript of the script's output.
    .EXAMPLE
    C:\PS> Log_Begin
    #>
    Process
    {
        $ScriptLoc = $MyInvocation.PSCommandPath
        $WorkDir = Split-Path $ScriptLoc
        If (!(Test-Path "$WorkDir\Logs")) {mkdir "$WorkDir\Logs" | Out-Null}
        $LogPath = "$WorkDir\Logs"
        $ScriptName = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($ScriptLoc)
        $LogDate = Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd"
        $LogName = "$ScriptName $LogDate.log"
        $global:Log = $LogPath + "\" + $LogName
        $ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
        Stop-Transcript | out-null
        $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
        # Create file and start logging
        If (!(Test-Path $Log)) {
            New-Item -Path $Log -ItemType File | Out-Null
        }
        Start-Transcript -Path $Log -Append
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can capture the batch file output? Preferably I wouldn't have to change every call to a batch file from the script, and make something in the module.

Comment: Looks like a bug, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160759/start-transcript-not-capturing-all-output-to-log-file

Comment: @BaliC Seems that the common workaround is to append '| Out-Host' to the end of the call. I've added it and will try and test. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, hope it works! :)

Comment: @BaliC Hi, that worked great! Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, then one of you should post that as the answer to this question so we can be done with it.

Comment: Please consider answering your own question to close this...